# Facebook for Android SSL: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, unity-game-engine

My app is having trouble connecting to Facebook in Android.  I can connect properly on iOS, but under certain circumstances on Android, I see this error in Logcat:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

The strange thing is that problem seems to be dependent on the workstation that builds the APK. If I build an APK in Unity on workstation A, Facebook will work properly.  However, if I try to perform the build on workstation B, the app won't be able to connect to Facebook and will display the error above. Both workstations can create working builds for iOS that connect to FB without issue.

I have verified that both of these workstations have the same Unity settings.  This includes:

- Inspector Facebook Settings

  - FB.Init() parameters
  - Android Build Facebook Settings
  - Facebook SDK version
- Player Settings

  - Android Bundle Identifier

I have also verified that the keyhashes appearing in the Logcat output have been added to the Android section of my Facebook App Settings page (one for each of the workstations).

I have also compared the AndroidManifest.xml in a "good" APK to the AndroidManifest.xml from a "bad" APK.  They appear to be identical, along with the rest of the APK contents (more or less).

I am wondering if anyone can offer an explanation as to what else could be causing this discrepancy.

Thanks